# Oracle PL/SQL does not recognize a DATE input?

Tags: oracle, plsql, date-formatting, plsql-package

I have package:

```
create or replace PACKAGE overload_pkg IS
  PROCEDURE what_am_i (p_x IN VARCHAR2);
  PROCEDURE what_am_i (p_x IN NUMBER);
  PROCEDURE what_am_i (p_x IN DATE);
END overload_pkg;
```

and body:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY overload_pkg IS
  PROCEDURE what_am_i (p_x IN VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN 
    pri('Here I am, a VARCHAR2');
  END what_am_i;
  PROCEDURE what_am_i (p_x IN NUMBER) IS
  BEGIN 
    pri('Here I am, a NUMBER');
  END what_am_i;
  PROCEDURE what_am_i (p_x IN DATE) IS
    BEGIN 
    pri('Here I am, a DATE');
  END what_am_i;
END overload_pkg;
```

Yet, when I call package PROCEDUREs:

```
BEGIN 
  overload_pkg.what_am_i('varchar2');
  overload_pkg.what_am_i(1234);
  overload_pkg.what_am_i('2018-04-06');
END;
```

, or any other date format I could think of, Oracle thinks it is either a VARCHAR or a NUMBER.  Output:

Here I am, a VARCHAR2
Here I am, a NUMBER
Here I am, a VARCHAR2

Statement processed.

The only thing that worked was...

```
BEGIN 
  overload_pkg.what_am_i('varchar2');
  overload_pkg.what_am_i(1234);
  overload_pkg.what_am_i(to_DATE('08-APR-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
END;
```

But I thought Oracle recognized dates, given that it does implicit conversions.  I am confused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `overload_pkg.what_am_i('2018-04-06');` Oracle is working correctly here. You are passing a string - a series of characters bounded by single-quotes. The fact that the value inside the string could be successfully cast to a date does not change that. What would you expect to happen if you change your second call to `overload_pkg.what_am_i('1234');`?

Comment: Oracle will convert a string to a date **only if needed** - that is, if a date is REQUIRED. In your case, a string works OK - Oracle doesn't need to convert it to string to "make things work." Perhaps if you had NOT defined a version that accepts a string, it would try to convert to date - but even then, that would fail because Oracle does **not** "recognize dates" (regardless of what you thought); it only "recognizes dates" that match the session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter. If your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `'dd-MON-yyyy'`, the input `'2018-04-06'` will NOT be recognized as a date.

Comment: @mathguy , more good info, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's expected; when you ran

```
overload_pkg.what_am_i('2018-04-06');
```

you passed a **string** to the procedure; see the single quotes and *something* in between? Well, yes - that's a string, `VARCHAR2`.

Implicit conversion doesn't count here; it might, if you used that string (that looks like a `DATE`) in some query. Oracle didn't have to convert anything here; you sent a string, it was detected, and appropriate procedure was executed.

If you want to pass a `DATE`, then do so - either by using the `DATE` **literal**, which always comes in `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'` format, or apply the `TO_DATE` function with the appropriate format mask.

Comment: Thanks, @Littlefoot.  That helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`DATE` literal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ):

```
BEGIN
   overload_pkg.what_am_i(DATE '2018-04-06');
END
```

From [How Subprogram Calls Are Resolved](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/08_subs.htm#i17794):

> To resolve a call among possibly like-named subprograms at the same level of scope, the compiler must find an exact match between the actual and formal parameters. **They must match in number, order, and datatype** (unless some formal parameters were assigned default values). If no match is found or if multiple matches are found, the compiler generates a semantic error.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  I am learning here.  I had used every date format I could think of but didn't know that "DATE literal" actually included the word "DATE".